# Detect RPi4 as usb network interface (g_ether/dwc2?)

Tags: usb, ethernet, yocto

## My issue

I am creating an image for my RaspberryPi 4 64 using Yocto and the meta-raspberrypi layer. I would like to plug the RPi into my laptop, have my laptop get an IP, and SSH into the RPi.

My issue is that my laptop does not "see" when I plug the RPi (i.e. nothing appears in `dmesg`). Also I don't see any USB network interface when I `ip l` in the RPi:

```
$ ip l
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:cd:0f:c4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

## What I tried

I did set `ENABLE_DWC2_PERIPHERAL = "1"` such that `config.txt` has the line:

```
dtoverlay=dwc2,dr_mode=peripheral
```

Which, in my understanding, tells it to set the micro-c to peripheral mode (not sure which usb is "dwc2", though... but I'm guessing it's the micro-c).

### Using kernel-module-dwc2

With the following Yocto line:

```
MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS += "kernel-module-dwc2"
```

I tried to make the following kernel module load at boot time (my understanding was that dwc2 was the module required for the USB chip of the RPi 4):

```
$ lsmod
dwc2 196608 0 - Live 0xffffffc008ac0000
```

At boot time, I see the following lines:

```
[    3.143331] dwc2 fe980000.usb: fe980000.usb supply vusb_d not found, using dummy regulator
[    3.152787] dwc2 fe980000.usb: fe980000.usb supply vusb_a not found, using dummy regulator
[    3.263285] dwc2 fe980000.usb: EPs: 8, dedicated fifos, 4080 entries in SPRAM
```

### Using kernel-module-g-ether

With the following Yocto line:

```
MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS += "kernel-module-g-ether kernel-module-usb-f-eem"
```

I tried to make the following kernel modules load at boot time (those are the ones I load on my pocketbeagle, where it works):

```
$ lsmod
usb_f_eem 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffc008ad1000
g_ether 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffc008af2000
usb_f_rndis 32768 1 g_ether, Live 0xffffffc008ae4000
u_ether 24576 3 usb_f_eem,g_ether,usb_f_rndis, Live 0xffffffc008ad9000
libcomposite 65536 3 usb_f_eem,g_ether,usb_f_rndis, Live 0xffffffc008ac0000
```

## Notes

I can boot into U-Boot, but I don't really know how to check that the device tree is setting `dr_mode` to peripheral for the micro-c (i.e. I don't know the address to pass to `fdt print`). I would like to verify that it is in peripheral mode.

Also I checked the kernel options with `bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel` and the USB gadget options were set as "M", so it seemed fine to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! I needed:

```
KERNEL_MODULE_AUTOLOAD += "dwc2 g_ether usb_f_ecm usb_f_eem"
MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS += "kernel-module-dwc2 kernel-module-g-ether kernel-module-usb-f-ecm kernel-module-usb-f-eem"
```

And the modules:

```
$ lsmod
usb_f_eem 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffc008aee000
usb_f_ecm 20480 1 - Live 0xffffffc008b18000
g_ether 16384 0 - Live 0xffffffc008b0f000
usb_f_rndis 32768 2 g_ether, Live 0xffffffc008b01000
u_ether 24576 4 usb_f_eem,usb_f_ecm,g_ether,usb_f_rndis, Live 0xffffffc008af6000
libcomposite 65536 4 usb_f_eem,usb_f_ecm,g_ether,usb_f_rndis, Live 0xffffffc008add000
dwc2 114688 0 - Live 0xffffffc008ac0000
```

`dwc2` needs `g_ether`, as per the log output below:

```
[   90.587953] g_ether gadget: Ethernet Gadget, version: Memorial Day 2008
[   90.594775] g_ether gadget: g_ether ready
[   90.599073] dwc2 fe980000.usb: bound driver g_ether
```

`usb_f_eem` is needed otherwise the usb interface is apparently not recognized properly on my laptop side, for some reason.

And `g_ether` loads all the other of the list above, i.e. `usb_f_ecm`, `usb_f_rndis`, `u_ether`, `libcomposite`.

Now I finally get my usb network interface:

```
$ ip l
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop qlen 1000
    link/ether dc:a6:32:cd:0f:c4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop qlen 1000
    link/ether c6:cf:14:d2:48:b9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

I must say I don't really get why I need `usb_f_ecm` here and `usb_f_eem` seems to be enough on the pocketbeagle. I would be happy to have some insights!